# Is it necessary to restrict Entity Framework access by singleton?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, singleton

Within the realm of Entity Framework, if I have 2 seperate classes leveraging a data model, do I need to ensure that there is only 1 reference to the entities object (singleton or similar)? In other words, in the scenario below, is there any danger?

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
        {
            //use _entities in some fashion here
        }
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
        {
            //use _entities in some fashion here
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsimmons/archive/2008/02/17/context-lifetimes-dispose-or-reuse.aspx) which you might find interesting about lifetime of data contexts.

Comment: Sure; the example was contrived. :)